# How to explain that one optimization problem formulation gives a faster solution than another?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

I have a relaxed convex problem (Conic) that can be expressed using two formulations. When solved using CPLEX, I obtained the same global solution. However, one formulation yielded the global solution in much faster time than the other. My question is how to explain these finding scientifically?

My guess is that the faster algorithm has a smaller feasible space which allow the solver to find the solution in a faster way but I can't prove this or even know if this is really the case. Any suggestion that can help in comparing the performance?

Comment: Conic problems are solved with the barrier method, and cplex will show the number of flops to do a cholesky factorization. So the number of flops could provide the scientific reason for the speed difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how to obtain this? I only managed to obtain the number of mip iterations and the number of branch and bound nodes explored. Is there any chance you may elaborate?

Comment: I have to mention that the problem is a mixed integer conic programming

Comment: The solution speed of a MIP has been shown to depend on how you order the variables, so not much can be said. You could still check the barrier statistics of the relaxed problem though.